# How to move a sticky positioned element to out of parent div?

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I want to move the `position: sticky` element to the right most of the parent element and again move out of the element. Like in this image:

[image]

But don't know how to do it. I know I can achieve this by `position: absolute` (That I did to get the screenshot.)

CSS

```
h1 {
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100%;
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Apparat</p>
    <p>Arcade Fire</p>
    <p>Same</p>
    <h1>Andrew W.K.</h1>
    <p>At The Drive-In</p>
    <p>Same`</p>
    <p>Chromeo</p>
    <p>Common</p>
    ....
```

I tried `left: 110%` and `px` values but didn't work. What I am got so far:

[image]

The codepen I am using: https://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/QapgYO

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use `position: absolute`?

Comment: Yes. I need a sticky behavior and my `fixed` hack is so buggy.

Comment: Just use `float: right`. See this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYZxGW)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like mentioned in the comment, just use `float: right;` for the `h1` and do some `margin-right` with minus values.

```css
h1 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  /* left: 100%; No need of this anymore */
  /* Other styles   */
  background: green;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 -100px 0 0; /* Changed to -100px right and 0 on the other sides*/
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}


/* Other styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: bold 18px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: orange;
  padding: .8em;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Apparat</p>
  <p>Arcade Fire</p>
  <p>Same</p>
  <h1>Andrew W.K.</h1>
  <p>At The Drive-In</p>
  <p>Same`</p>
  <p>Chromeo</p>
  <p>Common</p>
  <p>Converge</p>
  <p>Crystal Castles</p>
  <p>Same`</p>
  <p>Ted Leo & The Pharmacists</p>
  <p>T-Pain</p>
  <p>Chromeo</p>
  <p>Common</p>
  <p>Converge</p>
  <p>Crystal Castles</p>
  <p>Same`</p>
  <p>Ted Leo & The Pharmacists</p>
  <p>T-Pain</p>
  <p>Thrice</p>
  <p>TV On The Radio</p </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need the `h1` to be outside of the div just like in my picture.

Comment: @AsimKT I've updated my Snippet. This should do it now.